# Select any salary <3000 from emp table..please explain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

*Select any salary <3000 from emp table*..please explain

As I have seen answer as:

```
select * from emp  where sal > any(select sal from emp where sal < 3000);
```

But it seems that it will return all records with salaries greater than a minimum salary.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It does something like that.  I haven't figured out why SQL has the "any", "all", and "some" keywords.  There are usually more intelligible ways of writing such queries.

Answer (score 0):

Either you wanted to:

```
select * from emp where sal < any(select sal from emp where sal<3000)
```

Conclusion: you put '>' instead of '<'

Or  you just wanted to:

```
select sal from emp where sal < 3000
```

Comment: Is the first one a sort of random row selector ?

Comment: @Niemand : I think it will exclude the largest value from the result obtained by "(select sal from emp where sal<3000)" .
I believe that the perfect query will be like :

"select sal from emp where sal <= any(select sal from emp where sal<3000);"

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Operator any means "return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ANY of the values in the column that the subquery returns."

Comment: @user130240: imo the whole any statement is redundant and you should stick with select sal from emp where sal < 3000.

Answer (score 0):

The any statements returns all those entrys for which the comparisons evaluates to true for at least one of the entries returned by the query provided. Thus it returns all entries except the one that has no entry with a samaller salary

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will return all records greater than 3000 and you're correct.

```
  select * from emp where sal < 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed explanation of the **ANY** operator:

[Comparison Operators Modified by ANY, SOME, or ALL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187074%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Keypoints:

" >ALL (1, 2, 3) means greater than 3"

">ANY means greater than at least one value, that is, **greater than the minimum**. So >ANY (1, 2, 3) means greater than 1."